# IIS - http://mywebsite:80/website1, http://mywebsite:80/website2Server2 Possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a public API (Asp.Net WebAPI), where all calls start with the the url: /api/callName.

I have a second website that is the actual public MVC website.

I would like both of the above to be hosted on separate servers.

```
http://mywebsite:80/main/page1 should open my actual website, hosted on server 1.

http://mywebsite:80/api/call1 should open my API website, hosted on server 2.
```

Is this possible????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play around with IIS Web Farm and load distribution algorithms. So, one of the solutions: set up web farm, use load distribution in a manner when server1's weight is 100 for `http://mywebsite:80/main/page1` , while server2's weight is 0 for the same request and vice versa for `http://mywebsite:80/api/call1`